# How to get the user ID from the last profile page?

Tags: 7, users, emails

So, I have a user's profile page where there is a Message button. When I click the message button it should redirect me to a custom page with a form in it. How can I get the user ID from the profile page I visited in order to know where to send the message?

Comment: can you control the link of the message button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add the user id as a ref argument to the form url in your message button, on the user profile page:

```
<a href="/path/to/custom/form?userid=<?php print arg(1); ?>">go to custom form</a>
```

Then, on your custom form:

```
$args = drupal_get_query_parameters();
$userid = (isset($args['userid']) ? $args['userid'] : false);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I used in the end. I hoped that it would exist some drupal functionality for that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the user id from the **URL** of user profile page. The url will be like **/user/userid**. You can access it by arg(1).

Hope this helps..

Comment: Yes,  I know that. What I need is the ID when the user has moved to the message page; which is a different page than the profile page.

Comment: You can pass that through url, or you can save the id using **variable_set()** in user profile page and access it in message page using **variable_get()**.